# C++ main function's input arguments

Tags: c++

I'm writing (learning) an OpenCV code which I want users are able to input a cv::String file name (.xml) and a double type argument

My main function is

```
int main(int argc, const** argv) {
    ...
```

In cmd.exe, I want the program to be called like

```
> App.exe cascadedClassifier.xml 0.5
```

Where `cascadedClassifier.xml` is for user to select a classifier and `0.5` is a double type number for resizing image (frame)

One of my question is why the input argument is char type but the function to load classifier file require a `cv::String type` but it still works in the cmd.exe even though they're two different types of arguments?

The other question is what should I do in main function's input argument that user can freely assign a double type input for the program in cmd.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The C++ language specification defines the `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` [entrypoint function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) - it has nothing to do with OpenCV at all - similarly OpenCV is not concerned with your program's entrypoint either: OpenCV is a library, not an application framework (like MFC or Qt).
2. OpenCV's `cv::String` type [defines a constructor from `const char* s`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html#a3fcfff8db840709e39cd770100f2d886) which will be used to provide [an implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `cv::String`.
3. All command-line arguments are passed-in through `argv`, you cannot pass in non-`char`-type arguments with the standard C/C++ `main` entrypoint (this is because C and C++ do not define a convention for passing non-string arguments unlike, for example, PowerShell where Cmdlet arguments are defined in terms of .NET types). You will need to use `atof` or `sscanf` to convert arguments back into typed data.

Answer (score 1):

`const char*` can be implicitly converted to `cv::String` according to [the official cv::String Class Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d8f/classcv_1_1String.html).
*A double type input* is technically impossible in command line. You can use `atof(const char*)` function to convert `char*` type to `float`/`double` type in your function.